# How to get the absolute library file name corresponding to a relative path given to dlopen?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix, dlopen

In my program I have code like the following

```
/* libname may be a relative path */
void loadLib(char const *libname) {
   void *handle = dlopen(libname);
   /* ... */
   dlclose(handle);
}
```

Within `/* .. */`, I need to read the memory map file `/proc/self/maps`, to find the virtual memory address at which `libname` is mapped to and I also need to open the library to find certain sections in it. For this, I need the absolute name that `dlopen` found by searching in the various places (like, in the `ldconfig` cache file). How can I receive that file name?

---

This is what I finally ended up with (*yes, this is C++ code, nonetheless the C tag makes sense for this question because `dlopen` is used with both C++ and C and my question is eligible for both and POSIX specifies it for C.*).

```
   boost::shared_ptr<void> dl;
   if(void *handle = dlopen(libfile, RTLD_LAZY)) {
      dl.reset(handle, &dlclose);
   } else {
      printdlerr();
      return -1;
   }

   /* update sofile to be an absolute file name */
   {
      struct link_map *map;
          dlinfo(dl.get(), RTLD_DI_LINKMAP, &map);
      if(!map) {
         return -1;
      }
      char *real = realpath(map->l_name, NULL);
      if(!real)
         return -1;
      sofile.reset(real, &free);
   }
```

`libfile` is the relative / plain filename. The map will yield a non-plain file name (i.e not `foo.so` but may be `./foo.so`). Afterwards I used `realpath` to get the final absolute path name. It works nicely!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could use

```
... dlinfo(handle, RTLD_DI_LINKMAP, p)
p->l_name ...
```

where p is of type Link_map**

see man dlinfo for details

Comment: thanks. I did that and it works. I'll show my final way soon.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to mimic the system's algorithm.  This isn't as
difficult as it sounds (although as always, the devil is in the
details): I use the following to find the executable path:

```
std::string retval = our_argv0;
if ( !isAbsolute( retval ) )
{
    char const* tmp = getenv( "PATH" );
    if ( tmp == NULL )
        throw std::runtime_error( "$PATH not set" );
    std::vector<std::string> dirs( split( std::string( tmp ), ":" ) );
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = dirs.begin();
    while ( i != dirs.end() 
            && ! access( (*i + '/' + retval).c_str(), X_OK ) == 0)
        ++ i;
    if ( i == dirs.end() )
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot find load path");
    retval = *i + '/' + retval;
}
return std::string(
    retval.begin(),
    std::find( retval.rbegin(), retval.rend(), '/' ).base() );
```

You should be able to adapt it for a library, using the name of the
library instead of `argv[0]`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `PATH`, and
the appropriate default instead of throwing if it isn't set.  There
are probably special cases which it doesn't handle, but the above works
for us to find the executable.  (`split` and `isAbsolute` are other
functions in our library, which do the obvious things.)

Answer (score 0):

One option I can think of is using function `pathfind()`:

```
char *pathfind(const char *path, const char *name, const char *mode);
```

DL can be loaded from one of three locations: current directory, directory where the exec was located and LD_LIBRARY_PATH - you can check the last two - and use the `pathfind` with the `getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` for `path` parameter to try search for another one.

Comment: And where do you find `pathfind`?  I can't find it in the Posix documentation, nor even in the Linux docs.